# Javascript - safely extending functions

Tags: javascript, function, inheritance, prototype, extend

I've read several methods of extending functions on here and in other places, however I'm using the call syntax in my own implementation and I'm wondering if this is safe or if I will run into issues with more complex functions and objects?

Plunker -  http://plnkr.co/edit/Jbnxl505ZasuqeZlizh4 (check console output )

Code also below for reference

```
function test ( ) {

}

test.prototype = {
  init: function()  {
    console.log ("super");
  }
}

function subclass() {
  test.call(this);
}

subclass.prototype = Object.create(test.prototype);
subclass.prototype.init = function() {
  test.prototype.init.call(this);
  console.log("subclass");
};

var superclass = new test();
superclass.init();
var subclasser = new subclass();
subclasser.init();
```

Comment: To clarify - I'm pretty new to JS prototypes and scoping, I'm wondering if this can result in issues when I start manipulating objects passed by reference in more advanced functions or if it's a solid way to achieve extending by inheritance

Comment: Why do you have to create separate init function instead of using constructor directly?

Comment: This is just a sample, my actual code will be injecting angularjs scopes and setting $scope variables from the subclasses which will be specific to a controller type. Some scope functions will be common to all controllers, some will be specialised. Therefore I will have several basic functions which may have additional logic in various subclasses. In short for the same reason I might override a reverse() function in a spaceshuttle, boat and car which are all subclasses of vehicle.They should all signal the reverse and then do different things

Comment: What you've got looks alright. One thing to note is that for the subclass to be a direct descendant of the super class you should set the subclass' prototype equal to an instance of the super class, not the super class' prototype. As it is now, the two classes share a common prototype but subclass doesn't inherit from test. However, unless you're doing this for academic reasons I'd suggest against implementing your own JS class based inheritance and instead opt to use something readily available. I'd use John Resig's Class object. http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

Comment: Thanks, however if I set to an instance of the super class would the newly created subclass objects not share variables defined in that instance?